# Removing the horizontal scroll of the window affects the height of an inner DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, which is a simplification of a bigger code:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 /* overflow-x: hidden; /* uncomment this line */
}
.app {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center !important;
}
.left_panel {
 top: 250px;
 z-index: 20;
}
.panel {
 background-color: #aaeaff;
}
.panel_gallery {
 width: 256px !important;
}
.panel_gallery .panel_content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.middle_right_panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 z-index: 10;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
}
.middle_panel {
 margin-bottom: 270px;
}
.left_panel, .middle_panel {
 display: inline-block;
}
.middle_panel {
 transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
 <div class="app" style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="left_panel" style="position:relative;">
   <div class="panel panel_gallery">
    <div class="panel_content clearfix">
     abc<br />
     def<br />
     ghi<br />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle_right_panel" style="display:inline-block;">
   <div class="middle_panel" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="workspace" style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#80ff8f;" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the `JSFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/qwt8mfo9/

When the window has a low width, one horizontal scroll appears as you can see below:

[image]

I need to get rid of it.

Then I tried with `overflow-x` as below:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but then I get the following, where you can see the height of the content was affected, causing that `div` don't reach the bottom of the window:

[image]

Any idea on how to make that `div` reach the bottom of the window again after removing the horizontal scroll of the window?

If possible, please, provide some `JSFiddle` fork.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem -- for me, the vertical scrollbar remains consistent whether the horizontal one is there or not. It sounds like you have a graphical issue; there's certainly nothing in the code that should be causing that.

Comment: I can see this problem, on both, Firefox and Chrome and multiple computers.

Comment: @davidesp could you provide your current code in any online tools like codepen?

Comment: I already did it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

.middle_right_panel 
{

```
position: absolute;
top: -100px;
z-index: 10;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

### }

Replace css of ".middle_right_panel" with above code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give `height:100%` and here you go..
to resize check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qwt8mfo9/8/

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.app {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center !important;
  
}
.left_panel {
 top: 250px;
 z-index: 20;
}
.panel {
 background-color: #aaeaff;
}
.panel_gallery {
 width: 256px !important;
}
.panel_gallery .panel_content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.middle_right_panel {
 position: absolute;
 top: -100px;
 z-index: 10;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
}
.middle_panel {
 margin-bottom: 270px;
}
.left_panel, .middle_panel {
 display: inline-block;
}
.middle_panel {
 transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="app" style="display:inline-block;text-align:left;margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="left_panel" style="position:relative;">
   <div class="panel panel_gallery">
    <div class="panel_content clearfix">
     abc<br />
     def<br />
     ghi<br />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle_right_panel" style="display:inline-block;">
   <div class="middle_panel" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="workspace" style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:#80ff8f;" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```